# "SELECT something INTO variable" in trigger function's code creates a table named variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I discovered a mysterious table named `num` in my database which has one column named `count`. I had no idea how it got there, then I realized it might be caused by a misbehaving trigger.

I have a trigger function:

```
DECLARE num integer := 0;
BEGIN
  IF ... THEN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num FROM ...
  END IF;
  IF num > 1 THEN
    DELETE FROM ...
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
```

As you can see my purpose is to count the rows returned by a query and perform some operation if it is greater than one.

Can this faulty code be responsible for the unwanted table created? If so, how to fix this?

Comment: You are probably confusing PostgreSQL's PL/pgSQL with Oracle's PL/SQL.

Comment: @forpas: In PL/pgSQL this should be correct: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the **complete** trigger function. Unrelated, but you don't really need to run a `count(*)` to find out how many rows would be deleted.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did not know that, but since this is the case, why a new table is created? Is that feature version specific?

Comment: Sorry for opening the thread, I've found the cause. The SQL statement was run outside of the trigger as a normal select against the DB when testing which caused the creation of the "mysterious" table.

Comment: Yes, this is a footgun, and you found the explanation. For the benefit of others, you could sum up your findings in an answer. I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

[`SELECT ... INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) `foo` in PL/pgSQL stores the result of the `SELECT` in a PL/pgSQL variable `foo`. Whereas [`SELECT ... INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-selectinto.html) `foo` run as an ordinary SQL statement creates a table `foo` to store the result.

This is what caused the confusion, the table was created when I was testing the SQL statements from the trigger function manually against the DB.